# Display placeholder text in IE8 after Ember renders template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, internet-explorer-8

I found a script [(jquery-placeholder)](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to render HTML placeholder attributes on form elements in IE8. It can be easily called using:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Since Ember will be rendering these elements, I need to wait until they are rendered before calling this function. Is there an event I can bind to? Maybe I can add this to the a run loop queue?

Comment: Doesn't emberjs have a callback for when it is done rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As melc already pointed out, you should use the `didInsertElement` hook to implement this behavior. If you want to generally use this feature for all TextFields or TextArea, consider using the reopen method to modify/enhance Embers Default Implementations:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  placeHolderFunction : function(){
    this.$().placeholder();
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

This would automatically call the placeholder method on all Ember.TextField being used in your app (this one is used by the `{{input}}` helper). You could do the same for `Ember.TextArea`to implement this for textarea elements.

Answer (score 0):

A common place to manipulate the DOM is inside ember `view` classes, within the `didInsertElement` callback function.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

*examples of usage*

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AbebUQin/1/edit

```
App.Test1View = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement:function(){
    alert('test1 view inserted');
  }
});

App.Test2View = Ember.View.extend({
  myFunc:function(){
    alert('test2 view inserted');
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```